# What are the technical reasons why Virtual Box is limited to only use 256MB of video memory?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I saw, that Virtual Box can only use 256MB of graphics memory. Changing it in the settings file to be higher then the draggy-thing permits, always resulted in a crash (which is probably why they limited it to 256MB ;).
And I saw a LOT of people complaining about it on many forums. Searching through a couple of answers, I actually saw many (even contradicting) arguments, to why this is.

Since I am getting into virtualisation right now, I would like to know, why exactly this limit is in place. If it's "just a design thing", which follows the "256MB is enough, so we never expanded the capabilities even in the time of 4k resolution"-rule or is there a technical reason, why it would be bad/not possible for the virtual machines to use more then 256MB of graphics memory.

As far as I've understood it, the graphics memory is actually virtual graphics memory (what does that mean and what are the consequences of that in regard to the 256MB?)

Comment: 4k 3860*1920 =8m *4 bytes per pixel ARGB and the total size of 4k is 32mb  So 4k doesn't inherently require more than 256mb.  My guess is to prevent running of modern video games, as the performance would be awful. Plus it actually uses system RAM and not actual video RAM.

Comment: The reason you are unable to allocate more than 256 to your video memory, is due to fact you are not using VT-d (or the AMD equilvant).

Comment: It's also likely to do with "dedicated" and "shared" graphics memory the same as Intel iGPU solutions. Allocating more "dedicated" memory means you are permanently writing off memory on the host or guest, while "shared" memory is only used and allocated in the guest when needed.

Comment: @Ramhound what is VT-d (i am running an Intel chipset and dedicated graphics)

Comment: It stands for Intel Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O. It allows you to pass through physical hardware like a dedicated GPU to your VM otherwise your limited to the DirectX version of the Hypervisor